# Magento 2 admin, add new 'Text Field' into order information page?

Tags: magento2.2, adminhtml, design, page-layouts

Using `magento 2.2` `Admin`, I want to add `textField` into **Sale > Order > Information > Order & Account Information** like image. How to do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto below location:

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml

You can find the section you want. Now you can edit it according to your requirement. But before editing please **Override** this file to your adminhtml theme.

Also if you want to save those values to your order then you need to create 2 extra fields to your order table and also need to work on controller file to save accordingly.

Comment: Could give me `sample code` ?

Comment: You can create a magento 2 admin theme from here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html and then override

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info */ ?>
<?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php
$orderAdminDate = $block->formatDate(
    $block->getOrderAdminDate($_order->getCreatedAt()),
    \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
    true
);
$orderStoreDate = $block->formatDate(
    $_order->getCreatedAt(),
    \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
    true,
    $block->getTimezoneForStore($_order->getStore())
);
?>

<section class="admin__page-section order-view-account-information">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Order & Account Information') ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="admin__page-section-content">
        <div class="admin__page-section-item order-information">
            <?php /* Order Information */?>
            <?php if ($_order->getEmailSent()):
                $_email = __('The order confirmation email was sent');
            else:
                $_email = __('The order confirmation email is not sent');
            endif; ?>
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                <span class="title">
                    <?php if ($block->getNoUseOrderLink()): ?>
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Order # %1', $_order->getRealOrderId()) ?> (<span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_email ?></span>)
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewUrl($_order->getId()) ?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Order # %1', $_order->getRealOrderId()) ?></a>
                        <span>(<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_email ?>)</span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-content">
                <table class="admin__table-secondary order-information-table">
                <tr>
                    <th><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Order Date') ?></th>
                    <td><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $orderAdminDate ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php if ($orderAdminDate != $orderStoreDate):?>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __(
                                'Order Date (%1)',
                                $block->getTimezoneForStore($_order->getStore())
                            ) ?></th>
                        <td><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $orderStoreDate ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif;?>
                <tr>
                    <th><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Order Status') ?></th>
                    <td><span id="order_status"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_order->getStatusLabel() ?></span></td>
                </tr>
                <?php if ($block->isSingleStoreMode() == false):?>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Purchased From') ?></th>
                        <td><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getOrderStoreName() ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ($_order->getRelationChildId()): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Link to the New Order') ?></th>
                        <td><a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewUrl($_order->getRelationChildId()) ?>">
                                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_order->getRelationChildRealId() ?>
                            </a></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($_order->getRelationParentId()): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Link to the Previous Order') ?></th>
                        <td><a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewUrl($_order->getRelationParentId()) ?>">
                                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_order->getRelationParentRealId() ?>
                            </a></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($_order->getRemoteIp() && $block->shouldDisplayCustomerIp()): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Placed from IP') ?></th>
                        <td><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_order->getRemoteIp(); echo($_order->getXForwardedFor()) ? ' (' . $block->escapeHtml($_order->getXForwardedFor()) . ')' : ''; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($_order->getGlobalCurrencyCode() != $_order->getBaseCurrencyCode()): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('%1 / %2 rate:', $_order->getGlobalCurrencyCode(), $_order->getBaseCurrencyCode()) ?></th>
                        <td><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_order->getBaseToGlobalRate() ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($_order->getBaseCurrencyCode() != $_order->getOrderCurrencyCode()): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('%1 / %2 rate:', $_order->getOrderCurrencyCode(), $_order->getBaseCurrencyCode()) ?></th>
                        <th><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_order->getBaseToOrderRate() ?></th>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="admin__page-section-item order-account-information">
            <?php /* Account Information */?>
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                <span class="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Account Information') ?></span>
                <div class="actions"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAccountEditLink()?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-content">
                <table class="admin__table-secondary order-account-information-table">
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Customer Name') ?></th>
                        <td>
                            <?php if ($_customerUrl = $block->getCustomerViewUrl()) : ?>
                                <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_customerUrl ?>" target="_blank">
                                    <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_order->getCustomerName()) ?></span>
                                </a>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_order->getCustomerName()) ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?></th>
                        <td><a href="mailto:<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_order->getCustomerEmail()) ?>"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_order->getCustomerEmail()) ?></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php if ($_groupName = $block->getCustomerGroupName()) : ?>
                        <tr>
                            <th><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Customer Group') ?></th>
                            <td><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_groupName ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php foreach ($block->getCustomerAccountData() as $data):?>
                        <tr>
                            <th><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $data['label'] ?></th>
                            <td><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $data['value'] ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="admin__page-section order-addresses">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Address Information') ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="admin__page-section-content">
        <div class="admin__page-section-item order-billing-address">
            <?php /* Billing Address */?>
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                <span class="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Billing Address') ?></span>
                <div class="actions"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddressEditLink($_order->getBillingAddress()); ?></div>
            </div>
            <address class="admin__page-section-item-content"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormattedAddress($_order->getBillingAddress()); ?></address>
        </div>
        <?php if (!$block->getOrder()->getIsVirtual()): ?>
            <div class="admin__page-section-item order-shipping-address">
                <?php /* Shipping Address */ ?>
                <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                    <span class="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Shipping Address') ?></span>
                    <div class="actions"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddressEditLink($_order->getShippingAddress()); ?></div>
                </div>
                <address class="admin__page-section-item-content"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormattedAddress($_order->getShippingAddress()); ?></address>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</section>
```